# Is regex ever more efficient than string functions in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Whenever I see questions regarding regex on SO, everyone says that regex is slower than string functions. Are there cases when regex is faster than string functions? Or is regex purely for convenience?

Comment: Perhaps less for convenience, and more for flexibility... e.g. explode can only split on a single delimiter value, whereas preg_split can split on several different delimiter values in the one call

Comment: I'm not sure I would say regex is purely for convenience. In many cases it performs complex comparisons that would be tedious in basic string functions. Regex tends to be slower, but it's only fair to benchmark against equal operations.

Comment: @Mark: But you can use a loop and `strpos` to find each delimiter and use `substr` to split the string. It just takes longer to code.

Comment: Only a profiler can tell you for specific cases. It's however a common misconception that generic zend bytecode outperforms libpcre for complex string lookups (which it was designed for).

Comment: I guess it depends on how you optimize your regex too. In my experience regex are fast enough. Regex is a hammer.

Comment: @Linksu - and possibly longer to run as well; it would need to be benchmarked to know which is the faster method, but for a complex split the single-line regexp would probably be both faster and more convenient than a multiple operation loop with strops/substr - regexp is almost certainly less performant when simply replicating a simple built-in string function

Comment: But a regexp would also probably be better than basic string functions when working with UTF-8 strings rather than simply ASCII because it is multibyte aware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP is an interpreted script language, solving your problem using the least code possible is generally the most performing way of achieving what you want. And since regex is built-in, it should run much faster than any script despite of the complexities involved in its algorithm.

But naturally comparing both will depend on how complex it would be to mimic your regex in pure PHP code, so the answer to your question cannot be generalized. It will depend on each specific case.